# Ubuntu 15.10 - Nautilus Cannot Add Bookmarks

Tags: nautilus, 15.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my desktop PC, however I'm having a strange issue where I cannot seem to add bookmarks in the Nautilus file browser.

**ctrl + b** gives me no **+** option to add a bookmark

[image]

Nautilus version

[image]

I also cannot drag files to become bookmarks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go into a folder you want to bookmark in nautilus and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. This will add a bookmark, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> is only to edit the said bookmarks you already have.