# Ubuntu 16.04 -Nautilus Cannot Add Bookmarks

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

Same as in [Ubuntu 15.10 - Nautilus Cannot Add Bookmarks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750602/ubuntu-15-10-nautilus-cannot-add-bookmarks#new-answer).

Cannot add a bookmark, just edit. It is not fixed ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1- Using the nautilus file manager you can only bookmark the following directories:

- Local directories
- Directories on connected external drives
- Networks drives via SMB

2- Open Nautilus and navigate to the file you want to bookmark

3- Press  <kbd>cntrl + D</kbd>

4- Check the lower left panel to see if the folder has been bookmarked

5- You can also reorganize the given bookmarks order by typing  <kbd>cntrl + B</kbd>

If this method does not work try:

1- Go to the following path: `~/.config/gtk-3.0` (relative) or `/home/$USER/.config/gtk-3.0` (absolute path) and open the file bookmarks

2- Add there the path to any folder you want to have bookmarked (use the absolute path)

3- Save the changes and exit the document

4- Check Nautilus' bookmarks section

Answer (score 2):

To add a bookmark you must be inside the location you want to bookmark. Just clicking on the locations icon won't do.

Once you are inside the directory you want to bookmark press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Also note that the newly added bookmarks will appear below the drive list